# How to group only by month and year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, group-by

I'm rather vaguely familiar with SQL. I use SQL Server 2012.

I have this table:

```
|Id  | SiteId|    SiteDesc |IsNormal|     DateReview           |FrequencyId|
|3379|      5|     colon   |    1   |   2016-09-10 00:00:00.000|    1      |    
|3381|      5|     colon   |    0   |   2016-09-15 00:00:00.000|    1      |    
|3382|      5|     colon   |    1   |   2016-09-21 00:00:00.000|    1      |

|3489|      5|     colon   |    0   |   2016-08-10 00:00:00.000|    1      |    
|3851|      5|     colon   |    1   |   2016-08-16 00:00:00.000|    1      |

|3537|      2|     dogon   |    1  |    2016-05-05 00:00:00.000|    1      |    
|3863|      2|     dogon   |    1  |    2016-05-20 00:00:00.000|    1      |
```

`IsNormal` column is of `BIT` data type.

I need to group the table by `SiteId` and `DateReview` (only month and year). If  in `IsNormal` column at least one row has property false, in grouped table it has to be False.

Here is the desired grouped table:

```
 | SiteId|    SiteDesc |IsNormal|     DateReview           |FrequencyId|
 |      5|     colon   |    0   |   2016-09-10 00:00:00.000|    1      |        
 |      5|     colon   |    0   |   2016-08-10 00:00:00.000|    1      |    
 |      2|     dogon   |    1   |   2016-05-05 00:00:00.000|    1      |
```

Comment: @gaurav any item in the select with a group by has to be either in the group by or an aggregate: that does not meet this rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server can't aggregate `bit` columns as is, so cast it to `int` first, then use `MIN` and then cast it back to `bit`.

To group by month I use the following formula:

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '20010101', DateReview), '20010101')
```

You can pick any anchor date instead of '20010101', it can be any first day of the month. The idea is simple. `DATEDIFF(month,...)` calculates the number of months between the anchor date and the value from the table. This is integer number - how many times the boundary of the month was crossed. Then this number is added back to the anchor date. Result of this expression is the value of `DateReview` truncated to the first day of the month.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    SiteId
    ,MIN(SiteDesc) AS SiteDesc
    ,CAST(MIN(CAST(IsNormal AS int)) AS bit) AS IsNormal
    ,MIN(DateReview) AS DateReview
    ,MIN(FrequencyId) AS FrequencyId
FROM T
GROUP BY
    SiteId
    ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '20010101', DateReview), '20010101')
```

Comment: Just curious why not `GROUP BY YEAR(DateReview), MONTH(DateReview)`?

Comment: @Eric, In this case there is no difference. The formula with `DATEDIFF` is more generic. You can put `week`/`quarter`/`hour`/etc instead of `month` to group by some other interval.

Answer (score 3):

Use `year()` and `month()`:

```
select SiteId, min(SiteDesc) as SiteDesc,
       min(case when IsNormal = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as IsNormal,
       min(DateReview) as DateReview,
       min(FrequencyId) as FrequencyId
from t
group by SiteId, year(DateReview), month(DateReview)
order by min(DateReview) desc;
```

This simply uses the year and month for the aggregation.  It then pulls the column values using an aggregation function.  For `DateReview`, the appropriate function appears to be `min()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code you can try also.

```
 select  CAST(MONTH(SalesDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(SalesDate) AS VARCHAR(4)),  sum(TSalesAmt) as 'GrandTotal' from CreditSales group by  CAST(MONTH(SalesDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(SalesDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
```